# Date_Format in excel

Tags: excel, azure, powerbi, dax, cube

I have connected with my azure cube in excel.and there I have created date column.
How to change excel date format based on Our local system format.
Ex- if we have dd-mm-yyyy format in my local and if we open excel so date should be show dd-mm-yyyy format.if someone has mmddyyyy format so date date should be show mmddyyyy format.

How we can achieve.

Comment: It's not clear what are you going to achieve. Excel shows dates according to a local settings. If a work station is setted for ddmmyyyy you will see it, if mmddyyyy you will see it. If you get dates as string then, you can chage it with VBA.

Comment: I have created a pivot table and my data source is azure analysis services.which I am using for tabular model. I have created a dax query and it's datatype is date inside AAS. Basically date format is not working only for sweden.